# How to get userId for a given user in ADO using Azure DevOps API

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api

I have a requirement to add userId in the request body to add discussion in ADO , so any pointers how to get userId in ADO?

Comment: Hi Asit, any update on this issue, have your check my answer? does it answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Use this API:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/users/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP

Sample:

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://vssps.dev.azure.com/<Organization Name>/_apis/graph/users?api-version=6.0-preview.1' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic <Personal Access Token>'
```